# How to implement Callouts in Unix

Tags: unix

I am trying to implement my own thread library like pthread.
I want to use callouts to  call a function that updates priorities of threads after certain interval.

int to_id= timeout(fn,arg,time);

Can any one please provide some information regarding to how to use this and in which header file this function is available.

Is there any guide that help me to do this pthread implementation.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "function callbacks".  Start with this [tutorial](http://www.newty.de/fpt/callback.html) or this [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).